# error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Tags: c, embedded, stm32cubeide

```
#define NVIC_IPR_BASEADDR          (volatile)((uint32_t *)0XE000E400)

#define No_PR_Bits_Implemented     4

void GPIO_IRQPriorityConfig(uint8_t IRQNumber, uint8_t IRQPriority); 

int main(void)
{

void GPIO_IRQPriorityConfig(uint8_t IRQNumber, uint8_t IRQPriority) 

{

    //1. First lets find out the IPR register.

    uint8_t iprx= IRQNumber/4;
    uint8_t iprx_section= IRQNumber%4;
    uint8_t shift_amount = (8 * iprx_section) + (8- No_PR_Bits_Implemented);

    *(NVIC_IPR_BASEADDR + iprx * 4 ) |= (IRQPriority << shift_amount); //error line

}

}
```

Comment: Did you see any warnings from the compiler before that? `(volatile)((uint32_t *)0XE000E400)` is not a pointer due to the outer `volatile` defaulting to an `int` type as no explicit type is given. Try `((volatile uint32_t *)0XE000E400)`

Comment: @kaylum I consider that an answer. Would you like to create one?

Comment: The question should contain the complete compiler error (not just some program code and part of the error message as title).

Comment: Thanks yes i tried the same and problem was resolved. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

```
#define NVIC_IPR_BASEADDR          (volatile)((uint32_t *)0XE000E400)
```

That does not result in a pointer type. The outer `(volatile)` has no explicit type and will thus result in the type defaulting to `int`. With gcc for example, should get a warning similar to the following:

```
warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in type name [-Wimplicit-int]
```

The correct define should be:

```
#define NVIC_IPR_BASEADDR          ((volatile uint32_t *)0XE000E400)
```